# Media Queries with Skeleton framework

Tags: css, html, responsive-design, media-queries, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I am having trouble with: http://brybell.me/vipeepz/skeleton/

```
/* Smaller than standard 960 (devices and browsers) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 959px) {}

/* Tablet Portrait size to standard 960 (devices and browsers) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px) {}

/* All Mobile Sizes (devices and browser) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {

}

/* Mobile Landscape Size to Tablet Portrait (devices and browsers) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {

}

/* Mobile Portrait Size to Mobile Landscape Size (devices and browsers) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
    #logo {
        margin-top:400px;
        position:relative;
    } 
}
```

That is the media query code within the layout.css file of the skeleton boilerplate/ framework.

It does not seem to be picking up the media query, I have tried many things and it doesn't seem to be working.

There are two logos now, because I was doing some testing, but I really am just trying to do something simple similar to instagram's website. simple phone image with screenshot and then a logo and block of text beneath.

I would appreciate any and all help. Thank you very much. I have been frustrated with this because I had the site how I wanted it on desktop, but can't get things to reposition to where I want them to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inline style declaration is overwriting the media query in this case since inline styles have higher specificity. Try moving your inline styles into an external stylesheet and your media query for #logo should be picked up.

Comment: thanks, but I think it may be picking it up now, but the margin-top is not working.

Comment: What if you put your reference to layout.css after mine.css? Ie

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/mine.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/layout.css">